# How to assign object to a state in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to assign a JSON object to a state in react native.

```js
this.state = {
  card: null
}

_getCardDetails() {
  getItem('userData').then(data => {
    this.setState({
      card: data.user.creditCard
    })
  })
}

render() {
  const { card } = this.state
  return (
    <Text>{card}</Text>
  )
}
```

i'm getting the JSON object from a `axios` call to my backend. But I can't assign that object to state in React Native.

Response from `_getItem()`

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjo4MzY5NDc5ODk5fSwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMzU1NjkyfQ._tYykbMtegpl58Poat0w2PsMUpnGFypqFd_7P2s6wQ8",
    "next": true,
    "user": {
        "isProfileComplete": false,
        "createdAt": "2020-01-28T11:42:53.413Z",
        "_id": "5e302aa091741b14c0ef18bc",
        "phone": 8369479899,
        "creditCard": {
            "createdAt": "2020-01-28T11:42:53.440Z",
            "creditCardExpiry": "2021-01-28T11:42:53.440Z",
            "_id": "5e302aa091741b14c0ef18bb",
            "creditCardNo": 512723298971919,
            "creditCardCVV": 381,
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, although incomplete. Please provide the data returned from getItem, and the rest of the component.

Comment: @FMCorz please have a look at the response

Comment: The property `card.number` does not exist.

Comment: sorry my bad but just `card` is also not working, I'm getting `null` only

Comment: Your code is still incomplete

Comment: `getItem()` is not `_getItem()`. Is it a typo? Also you are putting the whole object inside `<Text>`, instead just see if you are able to see any inner property of card object.

Comment: @Jai yes it's a typo it is `getItem()`. tried putting just a single property but it returned nothing but `null`

Comment: Check if your data is really available.. and also cross check the value of `this.state.card` in the setState's callback. Also, try rendering the Text only if card is not undefined or null, I suspect it must be lost somewhere in rendering initial null/undefind state.

Comment: Change card:null to card:[] while you declare it at very first

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 this.state = {
      cardDetails: null,
    }


    _getCardDetails() {
      getItem('userData').then(data => {
        this.setState({
          cardDetails: data.user.creditCard
        })
      })
    }

    render() {
  const { cardDetails } = this.state
  return (
    <Text>{cardDetails.creditCardNo}</Text>
  )
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: So, by changing the variable name would do the trick? Can you explain why it should work?

Comment: you are assigning object to state called cardDetails, but when extracting in text it doesnt take object, there you render card.creditcardnumber thats it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but I found a solution, it is assigning the object but I've to re-render the DOM or page whatever.

So this line helped me `{card && this.state.card.creditCardNo}`

i'm checking if there's anything in card state